# Finding nonequivalent 3-cycles and edges of a given graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

So I have three graphs defined by the following nested list, I'm using this list notation instead `<->` notation because it is more convenient for another part of my code (not written here):

```
   g[delta_] := {{{1, 2}, {1, 4}, {1, 5}, {1, 7}, {2, 3}, {2, 5}, {2, 
     6}, {2, 7}, {3, 4}, {3, 5}, {3, 6}, {3, 8}, {4, 5}, {4, 7}, {4, 
     8}, {6, 7}, {6, 8}, {7, 8}}, {{1, 2}, {1, 4}, {1, 5}, {1, 6}, {2,
      3}, {2, 5}, {2, 6}, {2, 7}, {2, 8}, {3, 4}, {3, 5}, {3, 7}, {4, 
     5}, {4, 6}, {4, 7}, {4, 8}, {6, 8}, {7, 8}}, {{1, 2}, {1, 4}, {1,
      7}, {1, 8}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {2, 5}, {3, 4}, {3, 5}, {3, 6}, {4, 
     8}, {5, 6}, {5, 7}, {6, 7}, {6, 8}, {7, 8}}}[[delta]]
```

so that I can get a list of graphs using

```
   f4graph[omega_] := 
Graph[g[omega], VertexLabels -> "Name"]

Table[f4graph[omega], {omega, 3}]
```

The code below finds all of triangle subgraphs (3-cycles) in each of the above graphs

```
h = CycleGraph[3];
    s[delta_] := 
      Subsets[Range[VertexCount[f4graph[delta]]], {VertexCount[h]}];
    p[delta_] := 
      Select[Subgraph[f4graph[delta], #] & /@ s[delta], 
       IsomorphicGraphQ[#, h] &];
    n[delta_] := Length[p[delta]];
o[alpha_, beta_] := VertexList[p[alpha][[beta]]];
```

so p defines a list of triangles (as graphs) for any of the given graphs above and o gives a list of the vertex numbers that form a triangle in each of the three graphs e.g. `o[2,3]` gives vertices for the 'third' triangle in graph 2.

Some context to my issue: some of the triangles in these graphs are redundant for what I am looking at, for example, in the first graph, the triangle formed by vertices {1,2,7} is 'equivalent' to the triangles {1,4,7}, {2,3,5}, {3,4,5} because I can geometrically get to one of the latter triangles by some kind of symmetry, in this case (possibly compositions) reflections. {1,2,7} is also 'equivalent' to {2,6,7}, {4,7,8}, {2,3,6},{3,4,8}, this can be seen by using Graph3D for the first graph, rotating the graph a bit and noting the 'equivalence' between edges 15 and edges 68. More examples of what I mean by 'equivalence' are written below.In the context of  I gain no new information by looking at {1,4,7} if I've already looked at {1,2,7}. However, {1,2,7} is 'nonequivalent' the rest of the triangles of the graph, namely, {6,7,8}, {3,6,8}, {1,2,5}, {1,4,5} (which forms its own class of equivalent triangles of graph 1). I'm using the word '(non)equivalent' because I am not familiar with a term for this in graph theory.

It is easily seen in the second graph that there is only one triangle to consider, e.g. triangle {1,2,6}, we can rotate and/or reflect to get to all other triangles. In this case, I would like the list `p[2]` to reduce to just one of the triangles (any of them, as they are all 'equivalent').

So the upshot of my question is, how can I algorithmically reduce my list of triangles in `p` to give a list of triangle(s) that are 'nonequivalent' to each other. Quickly starting at graph 1, I'd expect 2 'nonequivalent' triangles from ALL of the triangles in `p[1]`, for example triangles from the following vertices {1,2,7},{1,2,5} OR any 'equivalent' version of this, e.g. {2,3,6}, {1,4,5}  OR {3,4,8}, {6,7,8}. Right now, `p[1]` consists of 12 triangles, I'd like the list to reduce to 2 'nonequivalent' triangles using this 'geometric' symmetry as a classification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe what you mean by "equivalence" is [Automorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_automorphism).

Your definitions (some of them changed a little):

```
f4graph[omega_] := System`Graph[g[omega]]
t = Table[f4graph[omega], {omega, 3}]
h = CycleGraph[3];
s[delta_] :=  Subsets[Range[VertexCount[f4graph[delta]]], {VertexCount[h]}];
p[delta_] :=  Select[Subgraph[f4graph[delta], #]&/@ s[delta], IsomorphicGraphQ[#, h] &];
n[delta_] := Length[p[delta]];
o[alpha_, beta_] := System`VertexList[p[alpha][[beta]]];
```

Then:

```
<< GraphUtilities`
n = 1;
t = Table[f4graph[omega], {omega, 3}];
tt = ToCombinatoricaGraph@t[[n]];
eqclasses = (Sort@Automorphisms@tt)[[All, System`VertexList@#]] & /@  p[n];
dd = DeleteDuplicates[eqclasses, Sort[Sort /@ #1] == Sort[Sort /@ #2] &][[All, 1]]

HighlightGraph[t[[1]], Subgraph[t[[1]], #], 
               GraphLayout -> "CircularEmbedding", 
               VertexLabels -> "Name"] & /@ dd
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you wonder which are the equivalent (automorphic) vertex arrangements for this Graph:

```
SetProperty[
   t[[n]], {VertexLabels -> Thread[Rule[Range@System`VertexCount@t[[n]], #]], 
             GraphLayout -> "CircularEmbedding", 
            ImagePadding -> 10}] & /@  Sort@Automorphisms@tt
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This can be achieved with `GraphAutomorphismGroup` and `GroupOrbits` as well.  But there's a problem which I think affects your answer too: there are 6 ways to write a triangle: 3 cyclic permutations and their reverse. The graph's automorphisms don't maps these into each other so some equivalences might be missed.  But I might be missing something ...