# Count graphs with fixed number of vertices incluing isomorphisms

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I'm trying to use the listgraph function in the Combinatorica package:

```
Needs["Combinatorica`"]
g = ListGraphs[5];
ShowGraph /@ g
```

However, it only returns all the non-isomorphic graphs. Is it possible to return the isomorphic graphs as well, or at least count the number of isomorphic graphs for each graph?

Comment: take a look at `Automorphisms[ ]`

Comment: Thanks. Yea I guess I could use Length[Automorphisms[ ]] for each element in g to count the degeneracies.

Comment: Is there a way to generate graphs with the vertex labeling fixed? It seems that with ListGraphs the vertices are indistinguishable. For example, if I have v vertices, then there are $v \choose 2$ pairs of vertices, and the total number of graphs generated should be $2^{v \choose 2}$.

Comment: Take a look at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/60725/193

Comment: And http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85771/193

Comment: Do you mean that you need to *count* all the *labelled graphs* on $n$ vertices?  Isn't the answer then just $2^\binom{n}{2}$, as you indicate in your comment?  What else are you looking for beyond this formula?  Or do you need to *generate* all these labelled graphs, not just *count* them, as the title would suggest?

Answer (score 1):

```
Needs["Combinatorica`"]
g = ListGraphs[5];
Grid[{ShowGraph@#, Length@Automorphisms@#} & /@ g, Frame -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]